# Can I reuse HTML "shell" created with jQuery for greater efficiency?

Tags: jquery, performance, append, each

I'm wondering what is the best way of writing the jQuery I need. Here's the task at hand;

- New content is loaded via AJAX, 12 objects at a time. Each object with have a link, some text and an image.
- The new content is inserted into an `<li>` element, with various classes and a `<span>` element nested inside. The HTML "shell" is all made using jQuery.
- I'm currently using jQuery's `$.each()` method to loop through the objects.

So, I'm wondering what the fastest script is for the job. I will need to create all the new HTML on each iteration of the loop, and I was hoping I could create the HTML once, and then reuse it, just adding in the different classes and content each time. I don't know if this is possible, or if this would even improve performance, but it seems logical to me. Secondly, what's better - appending to the parent `<ul>` on each iteration, or appending all 12 items at once "at the end".

You can see a very stripped down version of this idea on a jSfiddle I've put together: http://jsfiddle.net/D52EY/

Comment: Appending all items at once is definitely better, though at this scale you probably won't see any difference. )

Comment: @raina77ow I expected to hear that, but I'm trying to pick up good habits as I learn. I could push each item onto a new object or array and append this at the end I expect..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two questions actually.

Q: Should I create an HTML element representing a specific object from the scratch each time, or should I use some prepared template for that? Is the latter even possible?

A: Yes, it's possible; one possible approach for that:

```
var $tmplLi = $('<li>', { className: someClass, someOtherAttr: someOtherValue });
// when object's retrieved:
var $li = $tmplLi.clone();
$li.attr('id', someObj.id)
   .text(someObj.description);
```

As you see, I just clone the pre-created template element at each step. Note that `$tmplLi` is never attached into DOM - it just floats in memory, waiting to be used. )

This approach in some situation is way more readable, but is it faster? In our experiments, that turned out to be implementation-dependent; still, the difference was negligible.

Q: What's better: appending to the parent  on each iteration, or appending all 12 items at once "at the end"?

A: The latter is definitely better, but you probably won't see a difference when dealing with 12 items. ) Still, it scales far better, and is reasonably simple. The key point is using a container jQuery object, which contents are (again) not attached to DOM until it's required.

```
$container = $(); // empty jQuery object
arrOfObjects.each(function(obj) {
  var $li = createLiElementFromThatObject(obj);
  $container = $container.add($li);
});
// ...
$container.appendTo($somePlaceInDOM);
```

Comment: That's very interesting - I've never actually seen $() used before, only {} for an empty object. 

As for the speed, I think this is more of a readability advantage, as this allows the $.each() loop to be clutter free, which is nice. Thanks for taking the time to write.